# Export DB2 CLP output from a .sql file to .csv

Tags: sql, bash, db2

I am trying to export with headers, a large SQL query from DB2 CLP using below cmd.

```
DB2 -x " <LARGE SQL QUERY> "  >> /tmp/export.csv.
```

But it is returning a CSV that is including whole query and an error which says

```
SQL0437W Performance for this complex query maybe sub-optimal  Reason Code:1
```

Is there any other way to export a large query with headers to a CSV, preferable from a SQL file as input?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 separate questions in one, but you should restrict each question to one topic.

First is SQL0437W warning, so optimize your query because Db2 is complaining of a memory limit. Fix the query or adjust the config to avoid the warning. Use the Db2 Knowledge centre for your version of Db2 and your server platform to get tips for avoiding the warning. If you lack the skills then make a better question showing the exact query, and it's access plan from `db2exfmt`, or seek help from a competent DBA.

Second, the CLP `export` command (if that is what you are using) does not include column headers, and the `-x` [command-line-option](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=clp-options) to CLP explicitly omits headers.  There are answers on slashdot for how to get headers with the Db2 export command by running two queries, if you bother do your research.

Most people put the query (i.e. the [export](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-export) command) into a text file, and use the `db2 -txf  textfile` , and the query begins with `export to .... of del .... select ....` .